# Quarkus: Is there a way to exclude classes from automatic reload/recompile in the dev mode?

Tags: quarkus, activejdbc, javalite

When using JavaLite [ActiveJDBC](https://javalite.io/activejdbc) with Quarkus, this exception is generated:

```
org.javalite.activejdbc.InitException: you are trying to work with models, but no models are found. Maybe you have no models in project, or you did not instrument the models.
```

This happens because ActiveJDBC uses instrumentation after the compilation. The JavaLite instrumentation manipulates the class bytecode necessary for ActiveJDBC to function. This is done in a post-compile step before the app starts.

However, Quarkus reloads all classes from the source code in dev mode and hence kills the JavaLite bytecode instrumentation.

Is there a way to tell Quarkus to not reload/recompile certain classes?

Answer (score 0):

This question moved to Quarkus issues on Github here:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/35418